# jQuery, toggle menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following nav menu. 
If I click h1, t1, t2, t3 need to toggle (hide or show), other things stay as it is.

If I click h3, t6, t7, t8 need to toggle, other things stay.

Basically, h1, h2, h3 is the header and rest is children.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* In mobile menu, heading click, toggle sub */
  $('.slicknav_nav li.heading').click(function() {
    //$(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    $('.slicknav_nav li:not(.heading)').toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="heading">h1</li>
  <li class="first">t1</li>
  <li class="">t2</li>
  <li class="">t3</li>

  <li class="heading">h2</li>
  <li class="first">t4</li>
  <li class="">t5</li>

  <li class="heading">h3</li>
  <li class="first">t6</li>
  <li class="">t7</li>
  <li class="">t8</li>
</ul>
```

I have made some code. Obviously, it toggles other peer as well. Is it a way to only toggle the current item's "children"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nextUntil` of jQuery method like below.

```
$(this).nextUntil(".heading").toggle();
```

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* In mobile menu, heading click, toggle sub */
  $('.slicknav_nav li.heading').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".heading").toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slicknav_nav">
  <li class="heading">h1</li>
  <li class="first">t1</li>
  <li class="">t2</li>
  <li class="">t3</li>

  <li class="heading">h2</li>
  <li class="first">t4</li>
  <li class="">t5</li>

  <li class="heading">h3</li>
  <li class="first">t6</li>
  <li class="">t7</li>
  <li class="">t8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thought would be to wrap each heading group in a div, then wrap the children in another div inside that one. Could do something like this for layout:

```
<ul>
  <div class="headingContainer">
    <li class="heading">h1</li>
    <div class="childContainer">
      <li class="first">t1</li>
      <li class="">t2</li>
      <li class="">t3</li>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="headingContainer">
    <li class="heading">h2</li>
    <div class="childContainer">
      <li class="first">t4</li>
      <li class="">t5</li>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="headingContainer">
    <li class="heading">h3</li>
    <div class="childContainer">
      <li class="first">t6</li>
      <li class="">t7</li>
      <li class="">t8</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Then, in your jQuery, you could use the `.siblings()` selector to select the sibling div in the dom. Run `toggleClass("heading")` on the selection and that should do the trick if I'm understanding this correctly.